# My world needs a medium without friction but with weight; can I use liquid helium as that medium?

Tags: internal-consistency, physics

I'm building a world which needs a very cold medium with mass, but moving through this medium should be effortless.

Can I use liquid helium for this? An object placed in this medium experiences no friction, but is force needed to overcome the force given by its mass?

Answer (score 3):

You are probably thinking about [superfluidity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Superfluidity)

> Superfluidity is the characteristic property of a fluid with zero viscosity which therefore flows without any loss of kinetic energy. When stirred, a superfluid forms vortices that continue to rotate indefinitely. Superfluidity occurs in two isotopes of helium (helium-3 and helium-4) when they are liquefied by cooling to cryogenic temperatures.

It happens below 2.17 K, which is a tad cold for most applications.

However this doesn't mean that anything can move through it without friction. When an object moves through superfluid helium, it has to transfer part of its energy to it in order to displace it. Sure, the superfluid helium won't lose that kinetic energy, but it has first to get it.

Translated this means that motion through superfluid helium will experience friction, but the agitation induced in the superfluid helium will not dissipate, as long as the temperature stays below 2.17 K.

Comment: So if an object falls in liquid helium it looses part of its kinetic energy and will will fall further with increasing kinetic energy untill it reaches a constant velocity? When it has a constant velocity, no friction energy is radiated away then? Off course heat will be exchanged and a trail of bubbles will appear if the object is not perfectly isolated. Where will the loss of potential energy go? To heating up?

Comment: Beware that superfluid liquid helium has very unusual properties (exactly because it is superfluid). For example, it will climb the walls of any container and flood the surroundings to make its level uniform throughout.

Comment: And of course it takes significant effort to introduce an object into superfluid helium, since you can't exactly freely handle it under an atmosphere that freezes solid on contact with it, dumping heat into it in the process.